# How would I get the text written in an Entry Window from Tkinter and put it in a variable?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am an amateur at python and I am trying to make a program which sends whatsapp messages by typing your message and all the recipients in a tkinter entry window. I need to put the text written in the window into a variable so the program knows what to send and which groups to send it too. Here is my code:

````
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui
root = tk.Tk()
v = tk.IntVar()
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



def message_send(self=None):
    print(message)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Program Files(x86)/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')

    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)

    target_one = recipient_one.get()

    string = message.get()
    x_arg = '//span[contains(@title,' + target_one + ')]'
    group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH, x_arg)))
    group_title.click()





#This function contains the code for the main message interface. This also contains the recipient variables.
def begin():
    import tkinter
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("Whatsapp Message Creator")
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Write advert here:").grid(row=0)
    message = tkinter.Entry(window).grid(row=0, column=1)# 'username' is placed on position 00 (row - 0 and column - 0)
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Write recipient 1 here:").grid(row=1)
    recipient_one = tkinter.Entry(window).grid(row=1, column=1)
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Write recipient 2 here:").grid(row=2)
    recipient_two = tkinter.Entry(window).grid(row=2, column=1)
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Write recipient 3 here:").grid(row=3)
    recipient_three = tkinter.Entry(window).grid(row=3, column=1)
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Write recipient 4 here:").grid(row=4)
    recipient_four = tkinter.Entry(window).grid(row=4, column=1)
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Write recipient 5 here:").grid(row=5)
    recipient_five = tkinter.Entry(window).grid(row=5, column=1)
    send_button = tk.Button(root, text='Send', width=20, command=message_send) #message_send function will contain all the programming to send the message.
    send_button.pack()
    tkinter.mainloop()
window = tk.Label(root,
        text="""Welcome to the Whatsapp Message Creator!""",
        justify = tk.LEFT,
        padx = 20).pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Begin', width=20, command=begin)
button.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Exit', width=20, command=root.destroy)
button.pack()


root.mainloop()
tkinter.mainloop()
tkinter.mainloop()
```**strong text**

I have tried using the .get() function but it doesn't seem to work, and I can't find any sources that explain it properly. Could anyone help me? Thanks
````

Comment: basically from wt i understood frm ur Q, ig u shud use an `Entry` widget and use argument textvariable and set it to a variable(which you have to define prehand, like your `v`) or u can simply say `e1.get()` where e1 being the entry widget

Comment: Ah, okay, I will try that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: let me know if you want more help :D

Comment: if it worked i could ad it as an answer !

Comment: Yes, it did work! I no longer get an error message, however, I seem to get no data at all from the input. I think the method you suggested works, so definitely put it as an answer, it's just the way I've written the code. Do you think you could check? Can you see all the questions I've posted from my account, as I'll post the code in another question

Comment: yep jus let me know after youve posted :D